# Did something wrong with partitioning my SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, partition

I tried to make a partition for Windows on my Mac by using Apple's *Disk Utility*, because bootcamp already showed me that it didn't work for some reason. But now I'm stuck with a 70 gb hard disk, and I'm not capable of accessing the other part of the hard disk (I'm using a MacBook Air with 120 GB SSD).

I kind of expected *Disk Utility* to let me change the name and everything for this new partition I made (intended for Windows), but for some reason, the only thing that happens is that I can't access the rest of my hard disk anymore and there are no more partitions available.

I hope I've made clear what the problem is, I'm not a native speaker (as you might have noticed) so it's a little hard to write a question about a subject like this.

Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 732FEE77-68E5-4934-AEA2-EB01DE4EA90D
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Comment: @coen Please edit your question if you want to add additional informations instead of answering.

Comment: What kind of "hard disk utilities" did you use to partition your SSD? Apple's *Disk Utility*?

Comment: okay, sorry! I just couldn't really get the codethingy done...
I used Apple's Disk Utility indeed, nothing I have done so far has been done by a peer-made program

Comment: The `diskutil list` output doesn't reflect the observations you made in your question. The output shows the default partition layout of a CoreStorage LVG with one LV( and a Recovery HD) occupying the whole ssd.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a simillar problem, the disk verification in disk util shown minors errors, but it wasn't able to fix them. As such, I couldn't delete a fat32 partition.
Here is what I did :

- first i booted into safemode. The startup was long as it was fixing errors. (On boot, before startup chime, press and hold Shift)
- after that i booted in recorvery mode (the same: on boot cmd+r)
- when the recovery mode shown up, i did load the disk utility and deleted the partition.
  It worked this way.

However, You Should always do backups of your data, especially if you are messing with partitions